# How to use Jasmine like Mocha does on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

Hi there I was wondering how can I use jasmine like Mocha does w/ Chai.

So basically, in Mocha you just have to install it on node and then include it within your test files like this:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const should = require('chai').should();
const app = require('../app');
```

Then you automatically include some test and run `npm run test` and you can see the failing and passing test via the terminal.

While I tried to install jasmine via node using `npm install jasmine --save-dev` and then put the ff:

```
const expect = require('jasmine');
const app = require('../app');
```

And then tried some test:

```
describe('Multiply Numbers', function(){

  it('should return correct output', function(){
    let result = app.multiplyNumbers(2,2);
    expect(result, 4);
  });

});
```

I got the ff error:

```
> jasmine-test@1.0.0 test c:\xampp\htdocs\unitTesting\jasmine
> jasmine

Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.003 seconds
```

Any idea how can I run some test on Node js like mocha and chai does?
Also where can I find the assertion options (like expect, should..etc in chai) documentation?

PS. Here's what my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "jasmine-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to implement testing environment using Jasmine for node setup.

First Install Jasmine-node Module

```
npm install jasmine-node --save-dev
```

Create a tests directory and a spec file

```
mkdir tests
touch tests/myFirstTest.js
```

Now you can add your jasmine specs in this file, following the usual Jasmine syntax.
The documentation to be followed is here: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Add following in your spec file to integrate your app with the spec.

```
var myApp = require("../myApp.js")
```

One problem identified regarding this integration is that the specs may run again and again if server is not closed. For preventing this, just go to your application's main js file and export the close server function. Basically you need to add following in your app.js:

```
exports.closeServer = function(){
    server.close();
};
```

Be sure to close the server in afterEach jasmine function (refer doc above) as follows:

```
myApp.closeServer();
```

In order to run tests from terminal using npm test, just add this to your packages.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "jasmine-node tests"
}
```

You are all setup! Just run in your terminal,

```
npm test
```

Comment: the only problem with jasmine-node is that last commit was done 3 years ago. The project looks abandon.

Comment: Yeah it's possible. This is a nice alternative in that case: [Jasmine 2.5 with node](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/node.html)